# What information is missing from my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A few days ago I asked a question about resetting a WD Elements drive back to its factory format:

[How do I reset a WD Elements external hard drive to factory format?](https://superuser.com/questions/735459/how-do-i-reset-a-wd-elements-external-hard-drive-to-factory-format)

By now it did not receive any comments or answers and has also been downvoted. Is there some sort of information missing that I need to provide for people to understand the problem better? If so, what is is? Or is there some other problem with my question?

Answer (score 2):

The question looks fine to me. But it's a topic not many people will have knowledge about.

Comment: Thanks! So do you think there is a better place to ask this?

Comment: @Chris Probably not. You could contact WD support and ask them about this or post on the WD support forums (if those exist). If you find a solution somewhere else, be sure to answer your own question ;)